# Using Select-String to parse a cheat file for Yuzu

Tags: powershell, parsing, text, output

I figured out a working script to create the necessary folder structure and relevant .txt file for each cheat, but I am having problems figuring out how to parse the cheat file and use out-file to append and pipe out the cheat codes into the .txt files and in the correct paths that I created.

I understand that the Get-Content function reads the file line by line and that passing the -raw operator to it will read it multi-line. The online documentation is a little too much, and I can't figure it out. Here is the code that I have so far that creates the correct folder structure needed for Yuzu cheats from the cheat file:

```
$DirPath = "R:\Romancing SaGa -Minstrel Song- Remastered\01004A6017E8A000"
$FileName = "07a2419de0a62d94.txt"
 Get-Childitem $DirPath\*.txt |
ForEach-Object {
 (Get-Content $_) | Select-String '^\[(.+)\]' |
 ForEach-Object { $_.ToString().Trim("[","]").ToUpper() } |
 ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path "$DirPath\$_\cheats" -ItemType "directory" }
}
New-Item -Path $DirPath\*\* -Name $FileName -ItemType "file"
```

Below is the actual cheat file content for this particular game. For the code above, I have this file located inside of the "01004A6017E8A000" folder when I use it. I want to be able to get the block of code from the first bracket "[" all the way until it hits the newline "\n" but keep it formatted correctly and also out-file the cheat to the correct .txt file in each folder created by the script above. For example, the first cheat block would be selected and piped out to the .txt file in this path:

```
R:\Romancing SaGa -Minstrel Song- Remastered\01004A6017E8A000\ATTR 99\cheats\07a2419de0a62d94.txt

Next code below that one goes in:

R:\Romancing SaGa -Minstrel Song- Remastered\01004A6017E8A000\HP LP BP FILL\cheats\07a2419de0a62d94.txt
```

etc...

This will save me many headaches, especially with a game that has like 100 cheats or more, because copying and pasting each one of these into each text file is killing my mouse and my hand. :) Thanks in advance for any help getting this figured out.

```
[Attr 99]
04000000 01C62EE4 B9402100
04000000 01C62EE4 153D9B59
04000000 06BC9C48 580000A0
04000000 06BC9C4C A9020100
04000000 06BC9C50 A9030100
04000000 06BC9C54 B9402100
04000000 06BC9C58 16C264A4
04000000 06BC9C5C 00000063
04000000 06BC9C60 00000063

[HP LP BP fill]
04000000 03188D54 29442B89
04000000 03188D54 14E903B3
04000000 06BC9C20 29452B89
04000000 06BC9C24 2A0A03E9
04000000 06BC9C28 29052B89
04000000 06BC9C2C 29462B89
04000000 06BC9C30 2A0A03E9
04000000 06BC9C34 29062B89
04000000 06BC9C38 29442B89
04000000 06BC9C3C 2A0A03E9
04000000 06BC9C40 29042B89
04000000 06BC9C44 1716FC45

[Jewels 10000]
04000000 02FCAD88 B9402100
04000000 02FCAD88 14EFFBB8
04000000 06BC9C68 18000060
04000000 06BC9C6C B9002100
04000000 06BC9C70 17100447
04000000 06BC9C74 00002710

[Money 9999999]
04000000 02FCAD54 54000089
04000000 02FCAD54 5400008C
```

This is what I have so far that I have been trying to test. It gives errors about the path. I can't even test if my select-string code is grabbing the cheat code block from the Get-Content function correctly until I can get the variable for the path to the individual .txt files for each cheat to work in the code. Because of the second call to Get-Content, I can't use the $_ variable anymore because it would contain the new array of cheat code blocks instead of the folder names. At least, I think that is the way it works.

```
$DirPath = "R:\Romancing SaGa -Minstrel Song- Remastered\01004A6017E8A000"
$FileName = "07a2419de0a62d94.txt"
 Get-Childitem $DirPath\*.txt |
ForEach-Object {
 $CheatFolder = (Get-Content $_) | Select-String '^\[(.+)\]' |
 ForEach-Object { $_.Line.Trim("[","]").ToUpper() } |
 ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path "$DirPath\$_\cheats" -ItemType "directory" }
}
New-Item -Path $DirPath\*\* -Name $FileName -ItemType "file"

 Get-Childitem $DirPath\*.txt |
ForEach-Object {
 (Get-Content -raw $_) | Select-String '^\[(.+)\s*\$)' | Out-String | 
ForEach-Object { Out-File -Append -FilePath "$DirPath\$CheatFolder\cheats\$FileName" }
}
```

I am sure that I am making some kind of mistake with regard to how the array is stored for the folders for each cheat created by the first block of code. I am thinking that the $CheatFolder is supposed to be the name of the each folder created by the array from the first bit of code, right? It keeps giving me errors about the path in the Out-File section of code not being valid, and I can't see where I am getting it wrong. Little help here? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please format your code (sample/output data) properly using a [code block]? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code specifies "07a2419de0a62d94.txt", but your description talks about creating files by the name "07a2419de0a62d04.txt".  The one has a "94" at the end and the other has a "04" at the end.  Is this correct? Or should both be the exact same filename?

Comment: Oh, and I know that there are programs and python scripts with cheat databases that can do this, but I need to be able to do it myself with cheats that I find that are newer and not updated in these databases. That is why I am doing it myself.